# How to create reusable LWC to handle exceptions in JS?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, trigger, exception, es6

I have created a reusable LWC JS file

**lwcExceptionLogging.js**

```
const lwcException = (err) => {
    console.log(err.name+'--Name');
    var name = err.name;

console.log('log Name--'+name);

}
export {lwcException};
```

And imported it in one of my LWC JS component

**testlwc.js**

```
connectedCallback() {
   
    this.isdesktop=FORM_FACTOR === 'Large'?true:false;
try{
    var j = 1 / abc; 
} 
catch(err){
          
  lwcException(err);
}
}
```

Am able to call lwcException

But to pass the 'err' from **lwcExceptionLogging.js** to my **apexExceptionClass** Apex class value is becoming null.

Any idea how to pass '**err**' value to apex method where we are creating **Exception__c** object in apex class using ES6 modules?

Comment: You passing err to apex or err.name?

Comment: We need to pass 'err' as we need to insert err.name, err.message and other values to insert Exception__c object in apex

Comment: Can you show your apex also? how are you accepting err in apex method?

Comment: @auraEnabled
public static void saveLWCExceptionLog(err){

Exception__c exc = new Exception__c();
 exc.Exception_Message__c  = err.name;
 exc.Exception_Type__c  = err.message;           
   exc.IsClientSide__c = true;
 insert exc;   

}

Comment: You need to make Wrapper something for error object and then accept that wrapper parameter something like this - @auraEnabled public static void saveLWCExceptionLog(ErrorWrapper err) ... your ErrorWrapper contains name , message, etc

Comment: are you passing client side errors to server to save in to custom object or getting server errors in to client catch block and then pass to server again to save in to custom object?

Comment: Am trying to pass client side errors to server to save in custom object.